# Graph API: PUT /beta/groups/<groupId>/team Authentication Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

## Problem

`PUT` request to `/beta/groups/<groupId>/team` fails with the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e4385864-85e4-4fa6-8878-458988c584e4",
            "date": "2017-11-10T10:29:39"
        }
    }
}
```

A Bearer token is supplied, that was generated by using delegate permissions on `Group.ReadWrite.All`.

The endpoint is [documented here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams).

## Things I found so far

It seems, that it's something related to teams resources. The following requests do not work:

- `PUT /beta/group/<groupId>/team`
- `GET /beta/me/joinedTeams`

Both fail with `AuthenticationError`.

## Update

`/beta/group/<groupId>/team` does work now.

Comment: Could you please try using once using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: Using Graph Explorer works

Comment: Are you able to perform any other Microsoft Teams related operations using the same Auth token? (ex: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams)
Also, could you please provide the code snippet/steps?

Comment: I‘ll check this later. There is no code needed, I only used Postman for testing.

Comment: Have you obtained Admin Consent for this App ID on this tenant?

Comment: Admin consent is granted. Other operations like creating groups work.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?  I am having the same issue.

Comment: I had no luck until now. I think it‘s a Microsoft related error.

Comment: We'll take a look.

Comment: @Wajeed: /beta/me/joinedTeams does not work with the same token

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT, I am doing this through Flow and getting the same error.  Thanks

Comment: @JanKruse - how the Bearer token was acquired?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Using this method https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/ with the login.microsoftonline.com endpoint.

Comment: @JanKruse - Could you please try to get access token as documented in [Microsoft Graph Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I can try, but so we would have to store the refresh tokens as it is an continously running application, which must not require the user to be signed in as it‘s a service account.

Comment: @JanKruse - Could you please acquire access token for **https://graph.microsoft.com** (without trailing slash) and try again?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT it works now after removing the trailing slash! /joinedTeams does not work yet.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT it works with trailing slash too!

Comment: @JanKruse - _/beta/me/joinedTeams_ needs **User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All** permissions. Could you please try it after adding these permissions?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I‘ll have a look. But thus I don‘t need it in my project, I won‘t put too mich effort into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue when we acquire access token for **graph.microsoft.com/** with trailing slash. This has been fixed and now you should be able to call **/beta/group//team** using token acquired by tailing slash too.

*Note: Posting this as an answer so that other members need not go through all the comments.*

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone still running into this problem in 2018:**
Wajeed said they fixed the trailing slash token generation, which is only partially true. The trailing slash token generation works for succesfull requests but not for failing requests.

'*/beta/me/joinedTeams*' still returned an AuthenticationError for us. Only when we removed the trailing slash from the token generation we got a more descriptive error message telling us our test user did not have a Teams license.

Everything worked fine after granting our test user the correct license.

Comment: Add the right tags in your question. Can you edit it?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Can you please explain what you mean? i'm quite new to contributing on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can add tags when you make a question. If it is related to python for example, you pick this tag. Edit your question and see the bottom of the page. :)